# align="left" makes the table to float and in turn makes the height of the enclosing body to 0. How to get the actual height of the body?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <table align="right">
        <tr>
            <th> Row 1 </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> Row 2 </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a simple table with 2 rows. And the table has an attribute align="right". 
This parameter is adding the attribute float: right; at runtime and making the body height as 0.

I am using body height in some computation. So it is important me to get the actual height.

So my question is, How can i get the actual height of the body?

edit : I have many tables inside the body in my real application. The above is just an example. I can't go through each and every table, get their heights and sum it up.

Comment: The `align` attribute is obsolete and has been for several years.

Comment: Ok, so how can i get the actual height of the body that encloses the table?

Comment: You can't get the height of the body with html or css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var table = document.getElementById('mytable');

//variant 1
var rect = table.getBoundingClientRect();
var height_var1 = rect.height;

// variant 2
var height_var2 = table.clientHeight;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <table id="mytable" align="right">
        <tr>
            <th> Row 1 </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> Row 2 </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have many tables inside the body in my real application. The above code in the question is just an example. I can't go through each and every table, get their heights and sum it up.

Comment: how much? Why do you so sure it is a best practice to solve the problem?

Comment: as i told you the above is just a sample to understand the problem, in reality there could be hundreds of tables.

Comment: `var sum = 0, tables = document.getElementByClass('my-table-class'); tables.forEach(function(el) { sum += el.clientHeight; })`

Comment: Maybe using a lot of tables is not optimal decision for the task. Is it?

Comment: You've asked `How to get the actual height of the body?`. Here is a solution above

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We have tried this before, but causes performance degradation.

Comment: So you can set fixed height for table. Are you sure that `table` tag is more optimal than `div` one?